# What other breeds of dragons are known in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, dragons

Other than:

- Norwegian Ridgeback
- Hungarian Horntail
- Swedish Short Snout
- Chinese Fireball
- Welsh Green.

Are their other breeds of Dragon given in Harry Potter?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* lists ten breeds of Dragons.

> There are ten breeds of dragon, though these have been known to interbreed on occasion, producing rare hybrids. Pure-bred dragons are as follows:

The ten are:

- **Antipodean Opaleye**
- Chinese Fireball
- Common Welsh Green
- **Hebridean Black**
- Hungarian Horntail
- Norwegian Ridgeback
- **Peruvian Vipertooth**
- **Romanian Longhorn**
- Swedish Short Snout
- **Ukrainian Ironbelly**

> **Antipodean Opaleye**
>   The Opaleye is a native of New Zealand, though it has been known to migrate to Australia when territory becomes scarce in its native land. Unusually for a dragon, it dwells in valleys rather than mountains. It is of medium size (between two and three tonnes). Perhaps the most beautiful type of dragon, it has iridescent, pearly scales and glittering, multi-coloured, pupil-less eyes, hence its name.
>
> ---
>
> **Hebridean Black**
>   Britain’s other native dragon is more aggressive than its Welsh counterpart. It requires a territory of as much as a hundred square miles per dragon. Up to thirty feet in length, the Hebridean Black is rough-scaled, with brilliant purple eyes and a line of shallow but razor-sharp ridges along its back. Its tail is tipped by an arrow-shaped spike and it has batlike wings.
>
> ---
>
> **Peruvian Vipertooth**
>   This is the smallest of all known dragons, and the swiftest in flight. A mere fifteen feet or so in length, the Peruvian Vipertooth is smooth-scaled and copper-coloured with black ridge markings. The horns are short and the fangs are particularly 
>   venomous.
>
> ---
>
> **Romanian Longhorn**
>   The Longhorn has dark-green scales and long, glittering golden horns with which it gores its prey before roasting it. When powdered, these horns are highly valued as potion ingredients. The native territory of the Longhorn has now become the world’s most important dragon reservation, where wizards of all nationalities study a variety of dragons at close range.
>
> ---
>
> **Ukrainian Ironbelly**
>   The largest breed of dragon, the Ironbelly, has been known to achieve a weight of six tonnes. Rotund and slower in flight than the Vipertooth or the Longhorn, the Ironbelly is nevertheless 
>   extremely dangerous, capable of crushing dwellings on which it lands. The scales are metallic grey, the eyes deep red, and the talons particularly long and vicious.

Comment: @CHEESE The quotes provided are excerpts from their entries in FBawtFt.

Comment: Okay, that's what I assumed

Comment: @CHEESE as in, just excerpts, not the full entries.